# xsd two alternative optional tag

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to validate some xml like this:

```
     <Rpms>
        <Rpm>path/file.rpm</Rpm>
        <SlImport>path/file.xml</SlImport>
     <Rpms>
```

The tags **Rpm** and **SlImport** follow these rule:

1. are both optional
2. may appear more than once
3. may appear in any order, whether or not mixed
4. at least one (Rpm or SlImport) tag must be present

I wrote this xsd:

```
  <xs:element name="Rpms">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="SlImport" type="SlElement" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="Rpm" type="rpmElement" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

It works fine, except in this case: it doesn't throw error if **Rpms** tag is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ommit "minOccurs" attribute in "SlImport" definition, like

```
<xs:element name="Rpms">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="SlImport" type="xs:string"/>              
            <xs:element name="Rpm" type="xs:string" />              
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

because of empty "Rpms" is valid due the possibility there could be "zero occurence" of SlImport.

IMO wrapping "xs:sequence" is also redundant and could be removed.